# Monitor web service with Nagios check_http

Tags: web-services, monitor, nagios

I am trying to monitor a web service with check_http plug-in of Nagios.

The url I am trying to monitor includes url parameter.

And it turns out that check_http plugin will ignore the url parameter when checking.

Herewith my configuration.

## 'check_http' command definition

```
define command{
    command_name    check_http
    command_line    $USER1$/check_http -I $HOSTADDRESS$ $ARG1$
    }


define service{
    use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
    host_name                       pear
    service_description             HTTP
    check_command                   check_http!-u http://pear.com/total?eId=12345&env=abcde
    notifications_enabled           0
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Try replacing the value passed into `-u` with a relative path instead of the full URL.

In this example the hostname (`-H`) will be supplied by `$HOSTADDRESS$` which is taken from the `address` field of the `pear` host definition.
The value passed into the `-u` parameter should be a relative path, for example: `/total?eId=12345&env=abcde`.
We'll add the `-u` to the `check_http_with_args` command definition so we don't have to pass it as part of our parameters in our service definition.

```
define host {
        host_name                       pear
        alias                           pear
        address                         pear.com
        use                             linux-server
        contact_groups                  admins
        notification_interval           0
        notification_period             24x7
        notifications_enabled           1
        register                        1
}

define command{
    command_name    check_http_with_args
    command_line    $USER1$/check_http -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -u $ARG1$
}

define service {
        service_description             pear_total_http
        use                             generic-service
        check_command                   check_http_with_args!/total?eId=12345&env=abcde
        host_name                       pear
        contact_groups                  admins
        notification_interval           0
        notification_period             24x7
        notifications_enabled           1
        flap_detection_enabled          1
        register                        1
}
```

In the end, the command that Nagios execute should get translated into something that looks like this:

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_http -H pear.com -u /total?eId=12345&env=abcde
```

You can try executing the above from the command line to make sure it works for you.

**Note:** Replace the path to `check_http` with the actual path corresponding to your installation location on your Nagios server.

Relevant parts of the `check_http` man pages we're referencing:

> ```
> -H, --hostname=ADDRESS
>     Host name argument for servers using host headers (virtual host)
>     Append a port to include it in the header (eg: example.com:5000) 
> ...
> -u, --url=PATH
>     URL to GET or POST (default: /)
> ```

Source: https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_http.html

**EDIT:**

To answer your questions from the comment, the `-k` or `--header=` will allow you to pass in headers.

> ```
> -k, --header=STRING
>     Any other tags to be sent in http header. Use multiple times for additional headers
> ```
>
> Source: https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_http.html

So to specify an Accept header, I'd modify the following to look like:

```
define command{
    command_name    check_http_with_args
    command_line    $USER1$/check_http -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -u "$ARG1$" -k "$ARG2$"
}

define service {
        service_description             pear_total_http
        use                             generic-service
        check_command                   check_http_with_args!/total?eId=12345&env=abcde!Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
        host_name                       pear
        contact_groups                  admins
        notification_interval           0
        notification_period             24x7
        notifications_enabled           1
        flap_detection_enabled          1
        register                        1
}
```

...adding `-k "$ARG2$"` to the `command_line` of the `command` definition and adding the `Accept: <MIME types>` (for example `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`) to the `check_command` of the `service` definition.

Also, I wrapped `$ARG1$` of `-u "$ARG1$"` part of the `command_line` in double quotation marks as I suspect the `&` in `eId=12345&env=abcde` is causing the shell to think the end of the command is terminated just before the `&`.  Wrapping the parameter in double quotes should make it see the whole string as one whole argument.

Comment: Hi Young, how should i specify "Accept" header in command line?

Comment: Young, and i get error message like "required parameter env is not present"...seems like nagios only get the first parameter

Comment: Use the `-k` option to pass in additional headers.  Wrap the `$ARG1$` in double quotes to make sure it includes everything after the `&`.  See my edit.

Comment: It turns out that if you have "&" characters in your url_path, you absolutely have to put double-quotes around the macros in the command definition.

Comment: We have a permanent redirect in place and thusly needs -f follow as part of the command.         
cli: ./check_http -H yoursite.com -f follow -u subdirectory .         
command.cfg: command_line    $USER1$/check_http -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -f follow -u $ARG1$

Comment: Also important to note: check_command check_http!/<--- the forward slash is required for -u subdirectory check /somepath